# Can someone confirm one of these is the neutral wire?

Tags: lighting

Can someone confirm one of these is the neutral wire?[image]

Comment: Usually only smart switches have need of a neutral.  That looks like a three way(two switches for one light), so the two blacks will be travellers, not neutral.  There might be  neutral connections at the back of that box.

Comment: One would _hope_, @crip659 that the two blacks are the travelers (for simplicity sake), but there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: Are there any wires in the back of the box, not visible in this picture?

Answer (score 11):

If your house was properly wired according to NEC standards of the last 50+ years, *NONE* of the wires visible in that picture are neutral.

That looks like a 3-way switch where two of the wires are travelers and one of them is either the always hot supply or the switched hot going to the device being switched. (The travelers should be the ones connected to the two screws that are the same color while hot/switched-hot will be the one connected to the different color screw. Ignore the green screw - that's your ground.)

If you're looking for a neutral, look in the *back* of the box. You should see a bundle of white or grey wires that are all joined with one or two wire nuts. That should be your neutral bundle. Neutral wires are *not* switched (in 99.999%<sup>*</sup> of residential wiring situations), so you shouldn't find one connected to a switch.

If you do find two neutral bundles in the back of the box, be sure to figure out which one contains the neutral *for the circuit you're looking to modify*. If your wires are in cables (you'll be able to see a little bit of white or yellow cable jacket just inside the box, out of which the bare wires will spring), make sure the white wire goes into the same cable as the black or red you're messing with. If you have conduit, it's more difficult to tell - search this site for how to identify which neutral goes with which hot when using conduit.

---

As noted in a comment below, get rid of the "back stab" connections. They are definitely much easier to install - you just push the wire into the hole in the back of the switch. However, they fail much more easily than a proper shepherd's hook that's properly tightened down under a screw, too. That failure can lead to switches or outlets that stop working (at best) or fires (at worst). Really, it's worth the extra couple of minutes to fix that at every box you open.

Looking at the picture more carefully, it looks like those screw terminals are actually side clamps. You stick the straight wire behind the brass plate then tighten the screw down. Just as easy as the back stab, but much less prone to failure (especially if torqued correctly).

---

<sup>*</sup>OK, with the growth of smart devices, this is *bit* of an exaggeration, but with the exception of smart devices it does hold true.  Smart switches need to consume power to operate instead of just simply opening/closing the circuit through simple mechanical means, so they do need a neutral attached, but they don't actually switch it.

Comment: In addition to this fine answer, since you have the switch out, remove the backstabs and reconnect using the screw terminals. Do the other switches too. You'll thank me later.

Comment: Excellent point, @JACK!